# Is this metalogical diagram a reasonable presentation of untyped logics?

Tags: logic, knowledge-representation, modelling

**Diagram 1** represents my attempt to present the main components of classical predicate logic in a simple diagrammatic form. **Diagram 1** is about logic, not in a particular logic, hence the term *metalogical*.
This diagram is divided in into two sections, representing the syntax and semantics.

The taxonomic hierarchy represents is *part-of* relation, e.g. the symbols, syntax, and proof theory are part of a given logic.

The dotted  horizontal line represent a dependency between components e.g. without syntax proof would not be possible.

The green line represents the correspondence between syntactic and model theoretic proof.

**Diagram 1 (updated)**

[image]

Is this presentation reasonable? Should the domain of discourse be totally on the semantic side?

Comment: Maybe Formation rules are not at the level of formulas, because we use Formation rules to produce: *terms* (names) and *formulas* (phrases). And maybe you have to move "vdash" (the turnstile) under Inference rules, calling it Derivability.

Comment: In this way you can map Semantics on Syntax and Interpretation will map terms on objects of the Domain and sentences on "meaning" (truth values?).

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA Hopefully the updated diagram incorporates your suggestions.

Comment: 1. You may wish to distinguish the logical symbols from the non-logical symbols (the signature). 2. The domain is usually considered to be part of the interpretation, rather than separate from it.

Comment: @Bumble I have  incorporated your suggestions in the updated diagram.